# Intersection between values in python dictionaries (faster way)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to do a txt file with a result from an intersection of two dictionaries. I was searching and I know the best way to do this is with intersection of keys but with my dictionaries I can not do this.

Example of my dictionaries:

```
dA = {'1':'aaa','2':'aaa','3':'bbb'}
dB = {'10':'aaa','11':'aaa','12':'bbb'}
```

And this is the output I need inside the txt file:

```
1 10
1 11
2 10
2 11
3 12
```

Note: my dictionaries have ~100.000.000 entries each

This is my code:

```
>>> for key, value in da.items():
...     for bkey, bvalue in db.items():
...             if bvalue == value:
...                     print(key, bkey)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong ?

Comment: "but with my dictionaries i can not do this" <- why? Also how do you arrive at your output?

Comment: @MooingRawr sorry i copied bad my output i updated the question

Comment: @timgeb i updated the anwser with my code. But i want to know if there is a faster way to do this in python3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A faster method, which produces *unsorted* output.

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict

da = {'1':'aaa','2':'aaa','3':'bbb'}
db = {'10':'aaa','11':'aaa','12':'bbb'}

def gen_matches():
  map_a = defaultdict(list)
  map_b = defaultdict(list)

  for key, value in da.items():
    map_a[value].append(key)
  for key, value in db.items():
    map_b[value].append(key)

  for key in map_a:
    if key in map_b:
      for x in product(map_a[key], map_b[key]):
        yield x

for match in gen_matches():
  print(match)
```

**Output**

```
('2', '11')
('2', '10')
('1', '11')
('1', '10')
('3', '12')
```

This is O(n+m), which means it only needs to look at each element in each dictionary one time. We call the size of dictionary A "n" and the size of dictionary B "m".

The original method, is O(n*m). Every time you look at an element of A, you look at *every other element* in B.

So, you can get an idea of how long the two approaches will take by substituting numbers. If dicts A and B both contain 1000 elements, this version will take about 2000 time units, and the original would take 1,000,000!.

[Big-O notation](https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/big-o-notation-explained.html) is a way to *estimate* the complexity of an algorithm. I've linked you to a good beginner's guide; the wikipedia article is unfortunately rather hard to read.

Comment: oww! This is really fast! Thank you @Triptych. Can you explain me the big O notation here please?

Comment: Added some comments :)

Comment: Thank you @Triptych one more time ^^ I will read that article!

Comment: with python 3 using `for key in (map_a.keys() & map_b.keys()):` might be better then iterating over all the keys of one but otherwise very nice answer.